# Line breaks not occuring in for statement iterations

Tags: python

The follow takes multiple file inputs from a form and writes them in a serial method. While it does print when each file is successful to the page, line breaks are not occurring between each loop? What would be the best method to fix this? I thought `print` statements would add line breaks by default?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import shutil
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
"""

if 'file' in form:
   filefield = form['file']
   if not isinstance(filefield, list):
      filefield = [filefield]

   for fileitem in filefield:
       if fileitem.filename:
          fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
          # save file
          with open('/var/www/rsreese.com/files/' + fn, 'wb') as f:
              shutil.copyfileobj(fileitem.file, f)
          # line breaks are not occuring between interations
          print 'File "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully \n'
          message = 'All files uploaded'
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message)
```

Comment: In html you need <br> for a line break. Line feeds add a space only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python will print newlines just fine, but your *browser* won't show these.

Use `<br/>` tags instead, or wrap the whole output in `<pre>`/`</pre>` tags.